# Entity Framework - DbContext SaveChanges()

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, entities, savechanges

Can someone tell me is it possible, and if it is how to avoid using two times  `_context.SaveChanges()` in this code?

```
        Message m = new Message
        {
            Title = message.Title,
            Body = message.Body,
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };

        _context.Messages.Add(m);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        UserMessage messageToUser = new UserMessage
        {
            MessageID = m.ID,
            ProductID = message.ProductID,
            SenderID = message.SenderID,
            RecieverID = reciever.Id
        };

        _context.UserMessages.Add(messageToUser);
        _context.SaveChanges();
```

This is how my Entities look like

```
public class UserMessage
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SenderID { get; set; }
    public string RecieverID { get; set; }
    public int? ProductID { get; set; }
    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    public User Sender { get; set; }
    public User Reciever { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your UserMessage class, you set the reference instead of the foreign key, as the foreign key is not known yet.

In your code, that would mean:

```
    Message m = new Message
    {
        Title = message.Title,
        Body = message.Body,
        Date = DateTime.Now
    };

    _context.Messages.Add(m);

    UserMessage messageToUser = new UserMessage
    {
        ProductID = message.ProductID,
        SenderID = message.SenderID,
        RecieverID = reciever.Id,
        Message = m
    };

    _context.UserMessages.Add(messageToUser);
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks that was the thing !!

Comment: Isn't EF persistence ignorant, meaning: all changed entities are saved at a commit point, in the correct order? Just curious, because working with NHibernate, attempts to explicitly call insert/update to DB for single objects is a common mistake, except at the end of the UnitOfWork (usually by Flush() or transaction Commit()). The Save(object) method in NHib does in fact only attach an object to the persistence context (like EF Add()), not call immediate insert/update. Adding related objects by setting the ID is alse wrong in NHib, they should be added as described in this answer.